# How to use Javascript with HTML to embed video/mp4 MIME types ONLY

Tags: javascript, html, variables, mime-types

I'm creating a directory listing for a website.

Of course, I know how to embed videos normally using HTML, but I haven't really experienced using Javascript before, so I would appreciate any help.

Here is the code I have so far (minus the styling and extra stuff, etc):

```
 <TABLE>
         <TR>
           <TD class="widthdefine">Name</TD>
           <TD class="widthdefine">Size</TD>
           <TD class="widthdefine">Date</TD>
           <TD class="widthdefine">MIME Type</TD>
         </TR>

         <tr>
           <TD>
            <embed src="<!-- #echo var="DIRLIST_FILE_URL" -->#t=0.1" width="300" height="300" autoplay="False" preload="metadata">
            <p><A HREF="<!-- #echo var="DIRLIST_FILE_URL" -->" download>
            <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button>
             </A></P>
          
        </TD>
           <TD><!-- #echo var="DIRLIST_FILE_SIZE" --></TD>

           <TD><!-- #echo var="DIRLIST_FILE_DATE" --></TD>

           <TD><!-- #echo var="DIRLIST_FILE_MIME_TYPE" --></TD>
        </TR>
```

This code will just keep echoing all the files until it reaches the end. What I would *instead* like it to do is only display the files with the MIME type `video/mp4`.

Here is what I've tried:

```
<script>
if DIRLIST_FILE_MIME_TYPE = "video/mp4" {
document.write('<video src="<!-- #echo var="DIRLIST_FILE_URL" -->" width="300" height="300" autoplay="False" preload="metadata"></video>');
}
</script>
```

The code just above this replaced the `DIRLIST_FILE_URL` table cell (the one with the download button).

It doesn't return anything when I preview it.

I'm not very experienced with Javascript, so what do I need to do so it can filter the `DIRLIST_FILE_MIME_TYPE` variables to only show `video/mp4` files, AND how do I get it to correctly write the `<video>` embed tag into the actual website.

I'm not new to SO by the way, but I can't remember the email and password for my older account, so I've had to create a new one.

Comment: The correct syntax is `if (DIRLIST_FILE_MIME_TYPE == "video/mp4") {`. However, this is still unlikely to work because `DIRLIST_FILE_MIME_TYPE` isn't a defined variable with respect to the client-side javascript.

Comment: @Ouroborus You're right, it didn't end up working, but at least I learned the correct syntax! I appreciate the help, anyway. I'll probably just stick to using `<embed>` for now until I can work out a way to only get `video/mp4` MIME types.